# Laravel 5.5 and CKEditor Options

Tags: laravel-5, ckeditor

I want to use some of the optional extras, specifically video embedding, in CKEditor.

I have downloaded the entire thing to ckeditor in the public area, and in the plugins directory there is the video.

I start with the CDN of CKeditor:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and then I add the option for the video plugin:

```
<script>
 CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'video', '{{ public_path('\ckeditor\plugins\video\ ') }}', 'video.js' );
</script>
```

(The video.js actually is in a subdirectory dialogs which I have tried as well).

I can see the CKEditor which appears on my page but no video button.

Anyone any ideas please?

Comment: Where is laravel here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to upload the contents of the plugin archive to any folder on your website. Although, it is a good idea to name the folder so that you knew it holds CKEditor plugins. Let’s name it as ckeditor/plugins for the sake of our example. You should end up with the following path then:

```
ckeditor/plugins/jsplus_image_editor
```

Now, we need to tell CKEditor to load the plugin from the above folder. Add the following code to your HTML code above the line where CKEditor replaces the standard control:

```
<textarea name="editor1"></textarea>
...
<script>
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'yourpluginname', 
'/ckeditor/plugins/yourpluginname', 'plugin.js' );
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
...
</script>
```

Normally you install plugins trough the config.js but since you are using a cdn we need to replace the config. Update the above replace with the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', { customConfig: '/ckeditor/custom_config.js'});
```

make the above mentioned custom_config.js and place the following code
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

config.language = 'en';

config.extraPlugins = 'PLUGINNAME';

config.toolbar = 'custom';
config.toolbar_custom = [
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source' ] },
    { name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format' ] },
    { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] },
    { name : 'new_group', items: ['PLUGINNAME'] }
];}
```

hope this helps!